# ThreadSafe std::queue

Tags: c++, multithreading, thread-safety, queue

I have written a threadsafe queue and I would like you to suggest what can be improved and how to write good unit tests for this implementation.

```cpp
#include <mutex>
#include <queue>
#include <atomic>
#include <condition_variable>
#include <concepts>
#include <optional>

template<typename LockT>
concept Lockable = requires(LockT lock) {
    { lock.try_lock() } -> std::convertible_to<bool>;
    { lock.lock() } -> std::convertible_to<void>;
    { lock.unlock() }-> std::convertible_to<void>;
};

template<typename T, Lockable LockT = std::mutex>
struct ThreadSafeQueue
{
    ThreadSafeQueue() = default;

    void push(std::convertible_to<T> auto&& func)
    {
        {
            std::scoped_lock lock(lockT);
            queue.push(std::forward<decltype(func)>(func));
        }
        cv.notify_one();
    }

    [[nodiscard]] T pop()
    {
        T item = std::move(pop_opt().value());
        return item;
    }

    [[nodiscard]] std::optional<T> try_pop()
    {
        auto item = pop_opt();
        return item;
    }

    [[nodiscard]] inline std::size_t size()
    {
        std::scoped_lock lock(lockT);
        return queue.size();
    }

    [[nodiscard]] inline bool empty()
    {
        std::scoped_lock lock(lockT);
        return queue.empty();
    }

    inline void request_quit()
    {
        quit = true;
        cv.notify_all();
    }

    [[nodiscard]] inline bool quit_requested() const
    {
        return quit;
    }

private:
    [[nodiscard]] std::optional<T> pop_opt()
    {
        std::unique_lock lock(lockT);
        while (queue.empty() && !quit) {
            cv.wait(lock);
        }

        if (queue.empty()) {
            return std::nullopt;
        }

        auto item = std::move(queue.front());
        queue.pop();
        lock.unlock();

        return item;
    }

    std::queue<T> queue;
    LockT lockT;
    std::condition_variable_any cv;
    std::atomic_bool quit = false;
};
```

```cpp
#include <gtest/gtest.h>
#include <vector>
#include "ThreadSafeQueue.h"

TEST(ThreadSafeQueueTest, MultipleThreads)
{
    ThreadSafeQueue<int> queue;
    constexpr static std::size_t kNumThreads = 10;
    constexpr static int kNumIterations = 1000;
    std::vector<std::thread> threads;
    threads.reserve(kNumThreads);

    for (int i = 0; i < kNumThreads; ++i) {
        threads.emplace_back([&queue]() {
            for (int j = 0; j < kNumIterations; ++j) {
                queue.push(j);
            }
        });
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < kNumThreads; ++i) {
        threads.emplace_back([&queue]() {
            for (int j = 0; j < kNumIterations; ++j) {
                int value = queue.pop();
                EXPECT_GE(value, 0);
                EXPECT_LT(value, kNumIterations);
            }
        });
    }

    for (auto& thread : threads) {
        thread.join();
    }

    EXPECT_TRUE(queue.empty());
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    ::testing::InitGoogleTest(&argc, argv);
    return RUN_ALL_TESTS();
}
```

Comment: I would not that most people distinguish between `pop()` and `top()` (AKA `front()`). See: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/queue. pop() removes value without returning it, while top() (front()) returns the value.

Comment: You're right, but most of the time I use `front()` followed by `pop()`, so I think it's not that bad to connect these 2 functions into 1.

Comment: The usual reason for separating them is that a `pop()` that returns a value is not safe in the presence of exceptions. See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/25035949/14065 (I must admit I know of the rule but have not done extensive research and simply googled why they are normally seporated). Hence this is only a comment.

Comment: Hmmm... I need to delve deeper into this topic because before implementing my own thread-safe queue, I've looked at many implementations from other people and I don't think I've ever seen separate pop and front() methods.

Comment: I think in a multithreaded context you might want the `pop()` to return the value as you might not be able to `front()` then `pop()` the same value

Comment: Yep, Good point

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Why is there a template parameter `LockT`?

I don't understand why there is a template parameter for the type of `lockT`, but not for the type of `queue`. I think I'd rather have the type of queue be a template parameter, so that you could create one with a non-default allocator. Changing the type of lock is potentially dangerous; can your `ThreadSafeQueue` really guarantee thread-safety if it doesn't know that kind of lock is used?

I also don't see any use case for any of the mutex types from the standard library, other than the standard one. You are only using `std::scoped_lock`, so you will never benefit from `std::shared_mutex` or any of the timed mutexes. A `std::recursive_mutex` also doesn't make sense, since your class never recurses itself, and `mutexT` is `private` so nothing else could take that lock.

## Remove `size()` and `empty()`

I see these member functions often added to thread safe queue implementations. It might seem natural since it's like a container, and the standard containers also provide these functions. However, by the time `size()` and `empty()` return, the value they return might no longer be valid. So the caller should not trust the results, and is in fact better off not calling them at all.

## Missing `std::move()` in `try_pop()`

In `try_pop()` you don't use `std::move()`, resulting in a potentially suboptimal copy being made.

I recommend that you don't use temporary variables at all if they are unnecessary; this avoids needing to use `std::move()` to begin with:

```
[[nodiscard]] T pop()
{
    return pop_opt().value();
}

[[nodiscard]] std::optional<T> try_pop()
{
    return pop_opt();
}
```

Comment: Real question, why would the std move be necessary in try_pop? Wouldn't RVO be applied? I'll admit I don't even see why the std move is necessary in pop.

Comment: `empty()` is handy when background threads push into the queue and the main thread pops from the queue. Imagine there's a main loop `while(!quit) { ... }` and inside this loop, there's event handling, rendering etc. and the queue task execution: `while(!queue.empty() { auto val = queue.pop(); }`

Comment: @Alex Good point. Not all versions of C++ have guaranteed RVO, if you can rely on it then it wouldn't be necessary in `try_pop()`. In `pop()` it is different, the call to `pop_opt()` itself might use RVO, but then you have to get the value out of the optional.

Comment: @Edziju But now consider two threads, both doing `while(!queue.empty()) { auto val = queue.pop(); }`, and then you have a problem: they could both evaluate `queue.empty()` when there is only one item in the queue.

Comment: yes, so then there's something like this:

`while (!queue.QuitRequested()) {
    while (true) {
     if (queue.empty()) {
      break;
     }

     if (auto val = queue.try_pop()) { ... }
    }
   }`

Comment: @Edziju But then why not just do `while(!queue.QuitRequested()) { while (auto val = queue.try_pop()) {…} }`? You can do it without needing `queue.empty()`.

Comment: Alright, you got me :D

Comment: +1 for "remove size() and empty()". (There's arguably a valid use case for size() in statistics reporting, but even then it would be better to name it e.g. estimate_size() to avoid creating false expectations.)

Answer (score 5):

Think I see a race condition:

```
     thread 1:                         thread 2:
                                         pop_opt()

                                           std::unique_lock lock(lockT);
                                           while (queue.empty() && !quit) {
                                             // Thread de-sheduled.

       request_quit()
           quit = true;
           cv.notify_all();

                                              
                                             // Thread re-sheduled. 
                                             cv.wait(lock);
                                             // Thread stuck in wait
                                             // forever as it will never
                                             // receive a notify.
                                           }
```

Yes your `quit` is atomic, but the all the interactions between `quit` and `cv` also need to be atomic (i.e. inside a lock).

Comment: Okey, what if instead of `std::atomic_bool quit` I'd do `std::stop_source source`.

`request_stop()` function would do `source.request_stop()`.
and `pop_opt()` instead of the while loop -> `cv.wait(lock, source.get_token(), [&queue](){ return !queue.empty() });`

?

Comment: Would it be as simple as just adding a `std::scoped_lock` (or `unique_lock`) before `quit = true;`? I think so, unless I'm missing something. But good spot!